# R, data frame manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame in R.

```
X1 <- c(451,2,6,2,7)
X2 <- c(0,1,6,3,4)
df <- data.frame(X1, X2)
```

I would like to add two extra columns (X3 and X4), where the first row is mirrored (X3=X2 and X1=X4), and from the second row onwards, X3 equals X4 from the previous row plus one, and X4 equals X3 (same row) plus X1 (same row).

The final output should look like this

```
X1 <- c(451,2,6,2,7)
X2 <- c(0,1,6,3,4)
X3 <- c(0,452,455,462,465)
X4 <- c(451,454,461,464,472)
df <- data.frame(X1, X2, X3, X4)
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this in R?

Comment: Are those values in X3, X4 in expected correct

Comment: Are you sure that `772` value in your output is correct? That doesn't seem to follow any of the rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
a <- df$X1
a[1] <- a[1] - 1
b <- cumsum(a+1)

transform(df, X3 = c(X2[1], head(b+1, -1)), X4 = b)
  X1 X2  X3  X4
1 451  0   0 451
2   2  1 452 454
3   6  6 455 461
4   2  3 462 464
5   7  4 465 472
```

Answer (score 3):

Although there are much more efficient ways of going about this, writing a `for` loop is also a good idea:

```
X3 <- rep(df1$X2[1], nrow(df))
X4 <- c(df$X1[1], rep(0, nrow(df) - 1))

for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  X3[i] <- X4[i - 1] + 1
  X4[i] <- X3[i] + df$X1[i]
}

cbind(df, as.data.frame(cbind(X3, X4)))

   X1 X2  X3  X4
1 451  0   0 451
2   2  1 452 454
3   6  6 455 461
4   2  3 462 464
5   7  4 465 472
```

Answer (score 3):

`tidyverse` style using `purrr::accumulate`.

- `accumulate` or `accumulate2` rolls out result of previous iteration.  This result of previous iteration can be used as `..1` in lambda formula
- so our formula is `..1 + ..2 + 1` which is `result of previous iteration` + `first argument` and `1` (can also be written as `~ .x + .y + 1`
- Here I have stripped last value of first argument and
- took first value of `X2` as initial value (`.init`) instead.

```r
X1 <- c(451,2,6,2,7)
X2 <- c(0,1,6,3,4)
df <- data.frame(X1 = X1, X2 = X2)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(X3 = unlist(accumulate(X1[-nrow(.)], .init = first(X2), ~ (..1 + ..2 + 1))),
              X4 = X3 + X1)
#>    X1 X2  X3  X4
#> 1 451  0   0 451
#> 2   2  1 452 454
#> 3   6  6 455 461
#> 4   2  3 462 464
#> 5   7  4 465 472
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It's great. Would you mind adding some extra explanation for `accumulate2` function?